# Ubuntu software center not showing installed applications

Tags: software-center, synaptic

Ubuntu software center not showing installed applications after an auto-system update. only a white screen shows up. Also,applications which were installed before the update are not showing as installed in software center.

Please, help.

Thanks
Prizzly

Comment: did you ever post that bug? If so can you please post a link to it. After installing raring ringtail (13.04 dev) I cannot view installed programs, when I click the "installed" tab in the software center it shows the loading circle then the loading animation stops and it freezes. If I try to change back to the install tab it reverts back to the frozen installed software page, and if I try to search in the search box (upper right corner) it deletes my in outed text as if I am hitting refresh constantly but it doesn't know any refreshed content. So I think it's a bug with Ubuntu 13.04, because of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some times upgrades and updates have issues. This may be a regression and therefore need to be filed as a bug. Look at the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) and [how do I report a bug](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121/46312)